# Microsoft-Graph refresh-token request fails... AADSTS70000

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle, slim-3, refresh-token

I am using league/oauth client with guzzle in a Slim3 WebApp working with Microsoft Graph... and I am not able to successfully request a new token by given refresh token...

this is my di-container for league/oauth-client:

```php
$container['oauthprovider'] = function ()
{
  $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider(
    [
      'clientId' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_ID'),
      'clientSecret' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      'redirectUri' => getenv('ENV_REDIRECT_URL'),
      'urlAuthorize' => getenv('ENV_AUTHORIZE_URL'),
      'urlAccessToken' => getenv('ENV_URL_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
      'scopes' => 'offline_access user.read people.read user.read.all openid mail.send'
    ]
  );
  return $provider;
};
```

Works fine - in my Slim3-Route after redirect I got all tokens, refresh_token, etc.

```php
$provider = $this -> oauthprovider;
$CODE = filter_var($_GET['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$accessToken = $provider -> getAccessToken('authorization_code',
    ['code' => $CODE]
);

...

$existingAccessToken = $accessToken -> getToken();
$refreshToken = $accessToken -> getRefreshToken();
$expiresIn = $accessToken -> getExpires();
$expired = ($accessToken -> hasExpired() ? true : false);
$client = $this -> guzzzle;

...
```

And if I try to refresh my token at this point - in the same Slim3-route - it is working fine:

```php
$newAccessToken = $provider -> getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
    'refresh_token' => $accessToken -> getRefreshToken(),
    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
]);
```

But this is not my goal - I have to refresh the token by reaching the expired lifetime - 1 hour - in another Slim3-Route:

```php
$accessToken =  unserialize($session -> get('serialized_token'));
$refreshToken = unserialize($session -> get('serialized_refresh_token'));
$code = $session -> get('code');
$provider = $this -> oauthprovider;
$client = $this -> guzzzle;

...

$req = $client -> request('POST', 
    'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token', [
    'form_params' => [
    'accept' => 'application/json',
    'grant_type'=> 'refresh_token',
    'client_id' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'refresh_token' => (string) $refreshToken,
    'redirect_uri' => getenv('ENV_REDIRECT_URL')
  ]
]);
```

The Response:

> Client error: `POST https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70000: Transmission data parser failure: Refresh Token is malformed (truncated...)

The refresh token is exactly the same as what I got in my initial request.

Anyone experienced with oauth-client/guzzle/Microsoft Graph - What/Where is my error?

Comment: Please refrain from using profanity.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the v2 Endpoint, your `POST` should be to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` and your payload should include the `scope` property:

```php
$req = $client -> request('POST', 
   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type'=> 'refresh_token',
        'client_id' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'refresh_token' => (string) $refreshToken,
        'redirect_uri' => getenv('ENV_REDIRECT_URL'),
        'scope' => 'offline_access user.read people.read user.read.all openid mail.send'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Yes - i do so, Marc. I  request the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint. My initial request for an access-Token is working fine.

Comment: The problem is to get a new access-Token with my initial refresh-Token in a different Slim3-Route, after the first access-Token is expired. I do not know if the problem is `league/oauth-client`, the `Slim-DI`-Container, or something else...?

Comment: Thanx Marc, my request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` works fine - the response contains a new token and a new refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

For example - if i request Microsoft-Graph with my league/oauth-Client and guzzle via:

```
      $request = $client -> request('GET', "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", [
        'form_params' => [
          'accept' => 'application/json',
          'grant_type'=> 'refresh_token',
          'client_id' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_ID'),
          'client_secret' => getenv('ENV_CLIENT_SECRET'),
          'refresh_token' => (string) $refreshToken,
          'redirect_uri' => getenv('ENV_REDIRECT_URL')
        ]
      ]);

      $response = json_decode($request -> getBody() -> getContents(), true);

      echo 'Response: ';
      var_dump($response);
      exit;
```

The response contains the following information:

```
Response: array(7) {
  ["token_type"]=>
  string(6) "Bearer"
  ["scope"]=>
  string(45) "Mail.Send People.Read User.Read User.Read.All"
  ["expires_in"]=>
  int(3599)
  ["ext_expires_in"]=>
  int(0)
  ["access_token"]=>
  string(1901) "...f8SQPrPFsg66q8vHLGM4Q..."
  ["refresh_token"]=>
  string(847) "...cEksGS9XfHIqTH2LUYL..."
  ["id_token"]=>
  string(928) "...KKWAUtlyS0p5rDWILr..."
}
```

With this information i can renew my application token and refresh-token and keep on requesting the Microsoft-Graph endpoints.

Thank you, Marc! Great!